# Implicit operator overloading with boost::variant C++

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, boost-variant

Can anyone guide me on how to solve this problem.
I have a boost::variant.

```
typedef boost::variant <
int,
std::string,
bool,
double,
vector<int>,
vector<string>,
vector<bool>,
vector<double>
> boostVar;
```

I am trying to create overload `[]` operator as member function of a class `ABC` something like this (this is just a dummy implementation)

```
class ABC
{
    //some map of (key, value) pair that where key is string and value is of type boostVar
    boostVar [](const string key)
    {
       boostVar temp;
       //some operation that fills up temp based on value of key
       return temp;
    }
}
```

So while retrieving the a particular value using this implementation, it forces user to specify

```
int key1Val         = boost::get<int>(ABC["KEY1"]);
bool key2Val        = boost::get<bool>(ABC["KEY2"]);
vector<int> key3Val = boost::get<vector<int>>(ABC["KEY3"]);
```

my question is:

How should I go about implementing this if I want to access the values like below `(i.e. without boost::get<>)`

```
int key1Val         = ABC["KEY1"];
bool key2Val        = ABC["KEY2"];
vector<int> key3Val = ABC["KEY3"];
```

The implementation should give warning to user if the say: KEY1 does not match int, KEY2 does not match bool and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by "give warning to user"? A warning in what form? What exactly do you envision happening in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a class to wrap the boost variant and add the conversion behaviours.  At it's simplest - in the common case where realistically client code won't be trying to `delete` dynamically allocated instances using pointers to the base (`boost::variant<...>*`) - it could look something like this:

```
struct Variant : boost::variant<int, std::string, ...etc...>
{
    operator int() const { return boost::get<int>(*this); }
    operator std::string() const { return boost::get<std::string>(*this); }
    ...etc...
};
```

This will provide the same checks `get<>` provides: compile time checks that you're trying to assign to *one of* the types the variant *could* hold at runtime, and runtime checks that it does actually hold the exact destination type when you try to assign from it.

If you can't be sure client code won't `delete` via the base class pointer, consider private inheritance or composition (you will need to do more work to expose any other `variant` functionality your client code may want to access).

(`ABC::operator[](const std::string& key) const` can just return such a `Variant`).

Comment: Thanks @Tony. I was able to implement it. To learn such 'way of coding' can you recommend some books I can read. I am basically looking to develop my approach while solving such problems. And I would like to know if there is any book that teaches you different approaches/tricks to solving a particular problems.

Comment: @legameeternoforall: You're welcome.  Books - that's a big question (and off-topic, though S.O.'s C++ topic homepage has a recommended book list).  At one level, the "way of coding" there is applying a design pattern called an "adapter" - you can read about such things at a very high level in  [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).  For a gentle introduction to C++ template hackery, I'd still recommend Modern C++ Design by Alexandrescu.  But, I don't keep up with C++ book releases, so may not be the best person to ask....

Comment: I am finding this book very useful! This will certainly help me write clean and flexible code!